# How to start the Angular2 Application after the deploying into CentOS server

Tags: linux, angular, background-process, daemon, httpserver

I developed Angular2 application in VS-Code and created the /dist bundle using webpack , moved that dist directory to Linux server(Production). I want to start this angular2  application as daemon process which should not be terminated when i close the terminal. 
Present i installed http-server in linux and starting angular2 using the following command
=======>  `http-server -p 4200 /dist > output.log &`
After some time it is getting stopped or some other problems i'm facing using this way.
Is there any other better way to start the Angular2 application as background process. How in real time production every one do it??